# How to hide password from view when using 'scm login'

Tags: rtc

How can the password be hidden when using the 'scm login' command as described at http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/rtc/v1r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.team.scm.doc%2Ftopics%2Fc_scm_cli.html

I'm running commands as part of a script and its a potential security risk allowing the password to be outputted to the command window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can use [`lscm`](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/77813/what-is-the-diff-between-lscm-and-scm), as mentioned in [this thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/64097/lscm-command?redirect=/forum/questions/64097/lscm-command), you could cache the credential for all the subsequent scm to run.
However (as [mentioned here](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/64097/lscm-command?redirect=/forum/questions/64097/lscm-command))

> `lscm` will start a daemon process, and `scm` is a one shot deal.
> The daemon will load the SCM files and will reuse them on subsequent calls. That is the reason it can act poorly in automated environments.
> If you are using many commands together and decide to use `lscm`, make sure to clean up the daemon process at the end of the script.
> That will make sure the environment is clean for the next run.

Or: If you are login at least once with `scm`, as [detailed here](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/65727/using-quotscm-loginquot-command-with-c-option-cache-pw),  with `-c` option (cache the password on prompt):

> The cached password lives in ~/.jazz-scm/repositories.txt.
>
> The cached password is protected by filesystem permissions, and is obfuscated with a cryptographic algorithm.